# How to include the style to Angular unit tests

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli

Despite in my `angular.json` file under the `test` section I included the correct files in the `styles` array, whenever I run the tests using `ng test` the rendered components don't have the global style and look like just pure html, style-less elements:

[image]

How am I supposed to include the global css/scss to the unit tests run?

Comment: What's the specific reason to include the styles in the unit tests? Classes should be available with or without the style files to test upon them for existence etc.

Comment: for pure unit testing you're right, there is no need of the style. But if I want to write [Component DOM testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing) (also called "integration testing"), I need to properly render the component (e.g. without the style some parts of the component could be invisible or not accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons it started to work for me as soon as I've upgraded my app to use Angular 7.x